# Python Pymem MemoryReadError

Tags: python, python-3.x

I try to read and write an int value of a game which has different levels. You get every level 4000 goods but if you restart the level or continue to the next level, the value becomes for a second 0 and my python script exits with the MemoryReadError code.

When I take a look to the documentation it says:

for read:
read_int(self, address)
Raise:  pymem.exception.MemoryReadError if ReadProcessMemory failed

and write:
write_int(self, address, value)
Raise:  pymem.exception.MemoryWriteError if WriteProcessMemory failed

My Code:

```
while True:
time.sleep(0.1)

money = GetPtrAddress(gameModule + 0x0090E9C8, [0x0, 0x330, 0xA0, 0x84, 0x0, 0x310, 0x7C])


if money > 0:
    pm.write_int(money, 999999)

else:
    print("ERROR CODE")
```

Error Output:

```
File "C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymem\__init__.py", line 486, in read_int
    raise pymem.exception.MemoryReadError(address, struct.calcsize('i'), e.error_code)
pymem.exception.MemoryReadError: Could not read memory at: 13691336, length: 4 - GetLastError: 299
```

Now between the levels I see on CE that the value becomes 0 but still I don't get my print("ERROR CODE"), the python script exits immediately.

How can I handle this? Any Ideas?

Comment: Unclear why you need access to memory locations, but why aren't you using a try-except? We don't know how your game works, so not sure what else you're looking for

Comment: I'm new to python and I have tried try-except and it does not work either. The script terminates as soon as I restart the level.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include what you've tried?

Comment: I have fixed the problem by doing a try-except at read_int within my GetPtrAddress function. Now it works. Thanks for your help @OneCricketeer

Answer (score 1):

"read_int" is reading integer. To jump from pointer to pointer you need to read pointer value. Instead of reading integer, you can use "ptypes" see: https://pymem.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#module-pymem.ptypes

You can use ptypes like this;

```
from pymem import Pymem
from pymem.ptypes import RemotePointer

pm = Pymem("###.exe")

def getPointerAddress(base, offsets):
    remote_pointer = RemotePointer(pm.process_handle, base)
    for offset in offsets:
        if offset != offsets[-1]:
            remote_pointer = RemotePointer(pm.process_handle, remote_pointer.value + offset)
        else:
            return remote_pointer.value + offset

pm.write_int(getPointerAddress(pm.base_address + 0x123ABC, offsets=[offset1, offset2, offset3]), 123456)
```

Also;

```
pm.base_address
```

is basically the same thing as gameModule